# Какие возможны варианты задания аргументов для макроса, чтобы программа работала?

Tags: ассемблер, макросы, assembly

Я недавно начал изучать эту тему, поэтому не понимаю, какие аргументы подавать при вызове макроса mReadAX?

Согласно заданию, этот макрос должен ввести целое число в регистр AX в 10-значной системе счисления.

Вот сам макрос.

```
mReadAX macro buffer, size
local input, startOfConvert, endOfConvert
push bx
push cx
push dx
input:
mov [buffer], size
mov dx, offset [buffer]
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 0Dh
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 0Ah
int 21h

xor ah, ah
cmp ah, [buffer][1]
jz input

xor cx, cx
mov cl, [buffer][1]
xor ax, ax
xor bx, bx
xor dx, dx
mov bx, offset [buffer][2]
cmp [buffer][2], '-'
jne startOfConvert
inc bx
dec cl
startOfConvert:
mov dx, 10
mul dx
cmp ax, 8000h
jae input
mov dl, [dx]
sub dl, '0'
add ax, dx
cmp ax, 8000h
jae input
inc bx
loop startOfConvert
cmp [buffer][2], '-'
jne endOfConvert
neg ax
endOfConvert:
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
endm mReadAX
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас макрос определяется с двумя "переменными" - `buffer` и `size`

По коду макроса `mov [buffer], size` можно предположить что `buffer` это название регистра, а `size` это размер.

Поэтому исходя из вашего задания можно предположить что вам нужно использовать этот параметр с регистром **AX** и некоторым числом в качестве размера. К примеру если размер нужен равный **20** то использование будет вида `mReadAX AX 20`